# Compiling java files in all subfolders?

Tags: java, javac

How to compile all java files in all subfolders on Unix, using javac?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a build tool such as [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=maven&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). Both lets you manage dependencies in a much better way than can be accomplished using e.g. the `find` UNIX tool. Both And and Maven also lets you define custom tasks to be performed in addition to compilation. Maven furthermore comes with conventions for managing external dependencies in remote repositories, as well as conventions for running unit tests and features that support continuous integration.

Even if you just need to compile your source files once in a while, you'll probably find that setting up a simple Ant `build.xml` file can be a big time saver in the end.

Finally, most of the popular IDE and code editor applications has some kind of integration with Ant build scripts, so you can run all the Ant tasks from within the editor. [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/), [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and more also has built-in support for Maven.

Read [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) first, if you're new to Ant. Below is the example build file from the link:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>
        simple example build file
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile"
        description="generate the distribution" >
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
        description="clean up" >
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Once you're familiar with Ant, you'll find it easier to move to Maven.

Comment: Shouldn't the right answer be: "you do it like this... but Ant/Maven will work out better for you"? Someone who's actually trying to grasp how to use javac (what the question is aimed at) will not find an answer in this.

Answer (score 30):

On Windows...

Create a batch file:

```
for /r %%a in (.) do (javac %%a\*.java)
```

...then execute it in the top-level source folder.

On Linux...

```
javac $(find ./rootdir/* | grep .java)
```

Both answers taken from this thread...

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1518437&tstart=15

But as others suggested, a build tool would probably prove helpful.

Comment: thanks. I get this error message though: javac: invalid flag: ./lucene/org/apache/lucene/.svn/prop-base/LucenePackage.java.svn-base

Comment: oops, seems that file has a .java extension and you don't want to compile it, does it work with grep --include=.java? did it still compile your other files?

Comment: for /r %a in (*.java) do (jikes.exe -d bin\ -cp jre6\lib\rt.jar;WEB-INF\lib\\*.jar "%a")

Comment: for /r %a in (*.java) do (java -jar ecj.jar -d bin\ -cp jre6\lib\rt.jar;WEB-INF\lib\*.jar "%a")

Comment: On win10, got this error: `%%a was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if it is the best way, but this should work :

```
find . -name "*.java" | xargs javac
```

Comment: uhm, it doesn't work. Is maybe because find command works differently on mac ? (-name flag doesn't exist)

Comment: according to http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html the -name option exists.

Comment: Even if -name is supported, it won't work if a .java file exists in the current folder, since the shell will expand the wildcard. Use quotes (aka find -name "\*.java").

Comment: I modified the answer to add the quotes and the path to use. It should work on Mac OS X this time. And it works on Debian without the quotes : $ find . -name *.java --->
./test.java

Comment: Placing java files in 'default' package is anyway discouraged. You can't import that classes from any other package.

Comment: This won't work if any of the paths have spaces. If they do have spaces, do this instead: `find . -name "*.java" | xargs -I {} javac {}`

Answer (score 2):

Use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) to write a script to compile as many source folders as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) (as a more modern alternative to Ant).

Use an IDE, like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) (all IDEs I know will happily compile multiple source folders for you)

Answer (score 1):

Another (less flexible) way, if you know how much folder levels there are:

`javac *.java */*.java */*/*.java */*/*/*.java */*/*/*/*.java ...`

Depending on your shell, you may have to set it to expanding non-matching patterns to nothing, in bash with `shopt -s nullglob`. For example, I'm using the following shell function to find text in my java files:

```
function jgrep ()
{
    (
      shopt -s nullglob
      egrep --color=ALWAYS -n "$@" *.tex *.java */*.java */*/*.java */*/*/*.java */*/*/*/*.java */*/*/*/*/*.java
    )
} 

jgrep String
```

But really, use an build tool, as the others said.