# Compiling four java files within one package using javac

Tags: java, command-line, javac

I have four java files in my folder. They are all in the same package. Here's the package declaration
`package com.osama.GHide`

All of these classes are in the same package. I want to know how can I compile them using `javac` (i mean i do not know how to compile multiple files that are using each other). And once that is done how do I launch then using `java` command in the CLI? here are the file names.
`EnteringPoint.java` 
`HidingProcess.java` 
  `ListFiles.java`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194926/compiling-java-files-in-all-subfolders

Comment: You should not use `com.osama` as a package name unless you own the `osama.com` domain name.

Comment: thank you. I'll remeber that from now on.

Comment: Curious that two perfectly correct answers have been subjected to multiple downvotes.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

From the project's root directory:

```
javac src/com/osama/GHide/*.java
```

To run, assuming no other dependencies:

```
java -cp ./src com.osama.GHide.EnteringPoint
```

(Assuming `EnteringPoint` has the normal `main` function.)

The `javac` command compiles all the `.java` files in the package's directory. Since they're all in the same package/directory, this works. It also puts the generated `.class` files in the same directory, which may or may not be what you want.

To put them in a different directory, use the `-d` option and supply a path.

```
javac -d bin src/com/osama/GHide/*.java
```

Then to run:

```
java -cp ./bin com.osama.GHide.EnteringPoint
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run by using command :- javac -cp src/com/**/*.java
I am asuming there is no other dependenices and your root class name would be src only.