# Trying to compile Java source (could not find main class)

Tags: java

Trying to learn Java again and I cannot remember how I figured this out the first time around.

I have 3 classes; a GameLauncher, GuessGame, and Player. GameLauncher has my main method.

They are all packaged as chap02, I cannot remember if that is important to me yet.

I am compiling like this: javac GameLauncher.java GuessGame.java Player.java

running like this: java GameLauncher

I am getting this error: Could not find or load main class GameLauncher.

I know this is a ridiculous issue, but I have always had trouble with this kind of stuff. The actual programming and writing code I can pick up just fine, but dealing with these damn compilers always gets me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
package chap02;

public class GameLauncher {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    GuessGame game = new GuessGame();
    game.startGame();
}
}
```

Edit: The issue isn't with the actual code, the issue is with how I am compiling it.

Comment: show us the code and the error

Comment: Using NetBeans or Eclipse is easier. Otherwise, execute `javac` from the parent dir. This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027670/compiling-four-java-files-within-one-package-using-javac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the program, you have to run it form the correct directory. Remember, that you used packages, so you have the following package-structure

- src

  - chap02

    - GameLauncher.java
    - GuessGame.java
    - Player.java

after compilation, you will find the corresponding .class-files in the chap02-folder. To start the game, you have run the following command from the src-directory:

```
java chap02.GameLauncher
```

Since you specified a package in the source code, you have to use the full qualified name, including the package, to which the class belongs.

**EDIT** as vefthym mentioned, you have to compile the code in the same way, running

```
javac chap02/GameLauncher.java
```

from the source-directory.

**EDIT 2**
"src" is the directory, where your src lies. I, for example, have my Code unter X:\JDK-Projects[Project-name]\src. You have to specify the full absolute path to the src-Directory or the relative path form the directory you are currently in.

Comment: Does src mean the drive that my folder is in?

Currently the folder is in my c: drive, so would I do it like this from the command prompt? |||

cd c:\chap02 |||

javac chap02*.java |||

java chap02.GameLauncher |||

?

Comment: If all of you files are located under C:\chap02\src, then you should chdir to C:\chap02 and execute from there: 
cd C:\chap02 && javac chap02.GameLauncher.java && java chap02.GameLauncher