# Error: Could not find or load main class (Command Prompt). How Package name affect

Tags: java, package

My code like this

```
//package com.web_tomorrow;

public class RunThis1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Run ....RunThis1");

    }
}
```

When I run **javac** command with "package com.web_tomorrow"  **package name**  commented or not commented in both cases it can compile well.
But When I run **java** command with "package com.web_tomorrow"  **package name**, I mean not commented, it shows the Error: Could not find or load main class RunThis1
And if I comment/ remove the package name and then run the java command it executes.

Could anyone plz explain why java cant find RunThis1.class file while javac can find RunThis1.java from the same folder which is web_tomorrow ?

C:\JavaPractices\CPTest\src\com\web_tomorrow>java RunThis1
Error: Could not find or load main class RunThis1

C:\JavaPractices\CPTest\src\com\web_tomorrow>javac RunThis1.java

C:\JavaPractices\CPTest\src\com\web_tomorrow>java RunThis1
Run ....RunThis1

How java command is related to package name ? How package name is affecting java to find main class ?

My Envr variable classpath value is .

Answer (score 2):

Java packages are like directory. So if you have your class file MyClass.java in package like com.myfirm.pack then this should be in src directory like:

```
src
   com
      myfirm
          pack
              MyClass.java
```

if you wish to compile your java code (assuming you are at src folder) you need to do the following:

c:\src> javac  com\myfirm\pack\MyClass.java

While if you want to run it, you need to do:

c:\src> java -cp . com.myfirm.pack.MyClass

Comment: C:\JavaPractices\CPTest\src\com\web_tomorrow>javac RunThis1.java

C:\JavaPractices\CPTest\src\com\web_tomorrow>java -cp . RunThis1
Error: Could not find or load main class RunThis1

Comment: Try following commands: cd C:\JavaPractices\CPTest\src; javac com\web_tomorrow\RunThis1.java;java -cp . com.web_tomorrow.RunThis1

Comment: Can I run Java from pack directory, if YES then How ?  I can compile from pack directory but can not run java from pack directory

Comment: Yes if you want to run from web_tommorow use: java -cp c:\JavaPractices\CPTest\src com.web_tomorrow.RunThis1

Comment: Yes, it works, Thanks. But why javac can compile from web_tomorrow directory without -cp while java can not find from same directry ? why compiling and running find/manage to the file path in different ways, although .class and .java files are in same directory ?

Comment: That's a new follow up question. I would suggest you open new question and close this one.

Answer (score 0):

to compile this sources, you have to go into your src-directory. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761263/trying-to-compile-java-source-could-not-find-main-class/26761610#26761610) for a detailed explanation.