# Compile all files in src?

Tags: java, compilation, javac

Here's what I've got:

```
/myjava/compile.cmd
/myjava/src/a/HelloWorld.java
/myjava/src/b/Inner.java
/myjava/src/b/Inner2.java
/myjava/bin
```

HelloWorld:

```
package a_pack;

import b_pack.Inner;
import b_back.Inner2; 

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello, World");     

        Inner myInner = new Inner(); 
        myInner.myInner(); 

        Inner2 myInner2 = new Inner2();
        myInner2.myInner(); 

    }

}
```

Inner.java

```
package b_pack; 

public class Inner {

    public void myInner() {
        System.out.println("Inner Method");
    }

}
```

Inner2.java

```
package b_pack; 

public class Inner2 {

    public void myInner() {
        System.out.println("SecondInner");
    }

}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is compile this so I can run.

I could compile it with:

`javac -d bin src/a/HelloWorld.java src/b/Inner.java src/b/Inner2.java`

But I want to use a generic command that doesn't require listing every subfolder.
How do I do this?

Comment: Create jar file then....

Comment: You need to compile *all* of the files you reference, not seeing a way around that.

Comment: You should set up a build script with ant or maven and let it do this thinking for you.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - Is there a command to say 'compile every java file in all subdirectories'?

Comment: [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194926/compiling-java-files-in-all-subfolders)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `HelloWorld` class imports references to the `Inner` and `Inner2` classes, you can use javac `sourcepath` flag to compile all the three classes :

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src src/a/HelloWorld.java
```

Comment: yeah, nah, that gives me `package b_pack does not exist`. 

http://pastebin.com/pxQJJJyw

Comment: That's weird...From which directory are you calling the javac command?

Comment: Yeah, you didn't create a `b_pack` package. you created `a.pack` and `b.pack` packages. So you have to modify the names of the packages in the source files. In `HelloWord` class, you must have package ` a.pack` instead of `package a_pack`. In the two other classes, you must have `package b.pack` instead of `package b_pack`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, yup changing the src/a and src/b folders to src/a_pack and src/b_pack fixed it. Thanks.