# When use package, the javac only work in parent directory?

Tags: java

I use cmd to compile my java applications, but when I use package to pack all the files, if I try to compile them in the working directory, even if I use full path of the file, that won't work. But when I go to the parent directory, the same command works. And only works in parent directory, children directories or other directories also won't work. Can somebody tell me why? or is there any solution that make javac work in the working directory, because I use Sublime Text, its builder configs and binds the working directory.

Comment: javac expects you to honor the classpath. So you need to point whatever tool you are using to the root of your class paths, not at the java files themselves.

Comment: Try doing this: javac */*/*/*.java on Mac and Linux, but javac *\*\*\*.java on Windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5194940/3381825

Answer (score 1):

Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html to understand how Java source files should be organized. Espcially,

> ... put the source file in a directory whose name reflects the name of the
>   package to which the type belong...

By default the source code for `my.pkg.MyClass` must reside in `current_directory/my/pkg/MyClass.java`. You can use other than current directory with [javac option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) `-sourcepath`.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have two classes in two different packages `packagea` and `packageb` laying in the *parent directory*.

And class names are ***ClassA.java*** and ***ClassB.java*** respectively, and you have packaged your classes in these packages then you have 
to use `javac` command in parent directory like this:

```
javac packagea\ClassA.java packageb\ClassB.java
```

Your directory structure will be like this:

```
Parent_directory
  |
  |--packagea->ClassA.java
  |--packageb->ClassB.java
```

Otherwise, you can use any build tool like `ant` or `maven` to compile
your code. You have to just run `build.xml` file and your all files will
be compiled.