# Compile Java Files And External Lib Linux

Tags: java, external, javac

I've a Java project in IntelliJ which builds and executes successfully.
Now I would like to package the code (i.e. package it so it can be executed in a linux environment).

The directory structure is:

```
../parser/src/com/test1/java
bash-4.2$ ls -R
external  Jparser  Main.java

./external:
java-json.jar

./Jparser:
JsonParser.class  JsonParser.java
```

So far I've executed `javac -cp ../external/java-json.jar Parser.java`

What is the next step? Is it class path of Parser.java to main?

Edit:
I'm specifically interested to learn how to to the above in command line for better understanding of Java. I love gradle, maven, IDEs, but they all have sorts of black box magic which is often convenient but leaves the beginner user thinking they know Java builds....

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly to build a jar (with dependencies, if you have ones)?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy thank you for the reference. I'd like to learn how to build it on linux CLi (as a learning experience), and thus remove the black magic of Jet Brains (although I love it).

Comment: You can also create a runnable .jar with [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven?rq=1) or Gradle

Comment: Is there a way to do it in/command line?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194926/compiling-java-files-in-all-subfolders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear whether `Jparser` is a package inside your main module, or it is a sub-module directory.

1. If this is a package inside your only module, then

`javac -cp ../external/java-json.jar Main.java Jparser/JsonParser.java`

`jar cvf my.jar Main.class JsonParser`

2. If this is a module, then I'd copy Main.java and JsonParser.java to another directory and then

`javac -cp ../external/java-json.jar *.java`

`jar cvf my.jar *.class`

Then to run it: `java -cp my.jar:../external/java-json.jar Main`

A better approach to organize the build would be to use Maven https://maven.apache.org/ or Ant http://ant.apache.org/
IDEA can generate Ant builds using `Build->Generate Ant Build`.

Comment: thank you for the answer. `Jparser` is a class I wrote executed by `Main`

Comment: `./Jparser:` from this it can be seen that `Jparser` is a directory, so it cannot be a class, but it can be a package containing classes.